# nginx regex for catering to question marks

Tags: nginx

I am new to `nginx`. I have 3 endpoints to which I need to send POST and GET requests.

```
POST /v1/assessments/
GET /v1/assessments/assessmentID
GET /v1/assessments?type=all
```

The current entry for assessments in the default.conf looks like:-

```
location ~/assessments/(.*)$ {
   proxy_pass http://pma:4221/v1/assessments/$1;
   resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off valid=30s;
}
```

The current default.conf is not able to process the below endpoint:

```
GET /v1/assessments?type=all
```

How should I update the `default.conf` entry so that the above end point can also be accepted?